# How to break a string with numbers by symbol - split()?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a code:

```
single_amount_product = product_amount[i]

amount_products = single_amount_product.to_string().split('#')
```

product_amount is a list with items like that:

```
1
1#1
1#2
1
3#2#3
```

I want to break those into parts by split.
However I get: `'int' object has no attribute 'to_string'` (with or without `to_string()`)

The same approach works when I have text in the column (so I suppose this is because python automatically converts to int when it sees numbers?):

```
M3
M3#M3
KG
M3
KG#KG#KG
M3
M3
```

Comment: come on, it's not javascript ;)  `str(single_amount_product).split('#')`

Comment: [mre] is required. **what library** do you use? clearly there is no `.to_string()` method and it wouldn't help you at all if that really was an int because ints never contain `#`

Comment: I use: json,  pandas, numpy

Comment: [mre] is required. -- @bn_ln clearly `single_amount_product` is an int (check error message), so even if you convert it to string, it will never contain a `#`, so that split call is useless

Answer (score -1):

You can cast single_amount_product to a string before the split:

```
amount_products = str(single_amount_product).split('#')
```

Comment: there is no possible `int` value that, when converted to `str`, contains a `#`

Comment: That is true, but not constructive. The problematic element in his list is an int, not a string containing #. Python allows for lists to contain multiple data types. A blanket cast works here. Learn to be constructive, not ego-strokingly correct.

Comment: "constructive", sure, I asked OP for a proper MRE because the question, as it stands, is unanswerable, meaning not even you have enough info to answer it, even if the answer were sensible. did you read the error message that OP gave? it clearly states that the object is an `int` already, so your answer can't possibly do anything but return a 1-length list of the number. -- Stack Overflow is not something you should speedrun. you should learn a bit more about python and all the libraries you give advice on.